# Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'FileItem'

Tags: c#

I have loaded a text file using its path in a ListBox, but when I click on the listbox item, I get the following error :

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'FileItem'.

My Code :

```
public class FileItem
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
}

bool modelnameonly;

void reciperefresh()
{
    FileListbox.Items.Clear();

    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Recipe", "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    foreach (string f in files)
    {
        var fileItem = new FileItem
        {
            Title = Path.GetFileName(f), 
            Path = Path.GetFullPath(f)
        };
        FileListbox.Items.Add(fileItem.Title);
    }
}

string Fileloadpath;

private void FileListbox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var selectedItems = FileListbox.SelectedItems.Cast<FileItem>();
    var all = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, selectedItems.Select(x => x.Path).ToArray());
    FileLoadpath = all;
}
```

If I remove `Title` from  `FileListbox.Items.Add(fileItem.Title);` the error goes away, but the text displayed in the ListBox is *OpenCV.Form1+fileitem* instead of the actual file name.

Comment: In your `reciperefresh`-method you add just the fileitems `Title` which is a `string`, while in `FileListbox_SelectedIndexChanged` you try to cast the elements in that listbox into `FileItem`. Either save the entire `FileItem` into your listbox or have a dictionary that maps every `Title` to the actual `FileItem`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First we'll address the issue with the name in the listbox. By default, objects in C# return their type name when you call `.ToString()` (which is what the listbox does to get the display value). You can resolve this display issue by overriding your `FileItem` class' `ToString()` method:

```
public class FileItem
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Title;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, as M Bakardzhiev mentions in the comments, you could simply set the `DisplayMember` property of FileListbox to "Title".

---

Now you can simply add `fileItem` to the listbox:

```
FileListbox.Items.Add(fileItem);
```

So now, your code here should work:

```
string Fileloadpath;
private void FileListbox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender,
    EventArgs e)
{
    var selectedItems = FileListbox.SelectedItems.Cast<FileItem>();
    var all = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, selectedItems.Select(x
    => x.Path).ToArray());
    FileLoadpath = all;

}
```

Comment: Alternatively, he can bind DisplayMember to the fileitem's title.

Comment: @john : Thank you, overriding the tostring method worked.