# Unable to cast object of type 'System.string' to type '....Event'

Tags: c#

I'm making a personal calendar/planner thing and I want to be able to click on an even in the list box and have it fill out the title and time forms. I've been searching through every forum post on similar issues but they usually just give more errors. Currently, when I click on the event in the list box, the program exits and just gives an Unhandled Exception error saying `System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'ProjectName.Event'.'`

This is the code that throws the error:

```
    private void LstEvents_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnDelete.Enabled = true; // When something is selected, enable delete button

        Event eventtest = (Event)lstEvents.SelectedItem; // <--- This line throws error
        txtTitle.Text = eventtest.eventTitle.ToString();
    }
```

And this is my Event class:

```
public class Event
{
    int month, day, year, startHour, startMin, endHour, endMin;
    private DateTime startTime, endTime;
    public string eventTitle;

    public Event(int cMonth, int cDay, int cYear, int cStartHour, int cStartMin, int cEndHour, int cEndMin, string cEventTitle)
    {
        month = cMonth;
        day = cDay;
        year = cYear;
        startHour = cStartHour;
        startMin = cStartMin;
        endHour = cEndHour;
        endMin = cEndMin;
        eventTitle = cEventTitle;

        string tempDate = year.ToString() + "-" + month.ToString() + "-" + day.ToString() + " " + startHour.ToString() + ":" + startMin.ToString();
        startTime = DateTime.Parse(tempDate); // Convert startHour to DateTime

        tempDate = year.ToString() + "-" + month.ToString() + "-" + day.ToString() + " " + endHour.ToString() + ":" + endMin.ToString();
        endTime = DateTime.Parse(tempDate); // Do the same thing to endTime
    }

    public DateTime whenStartTime
    {
        get { return startTime; }
    }

    public DateTime whenEndTime
    {
        get { return endTime; }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return startTime.Year + "-" + startTime.Month + "-" + startTime.Day + " " + startTime.Hour + ":" + startTime.Minute; 
    }
}
```

Populating the list box:

```
    private void BtnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Event newEvent;

        newEvent = new Event(monthCalendar.SelectionStart.Month, monthCalendar.SelectionStart.Day, monthCalendar.SelectionStart.Year,
                             Convert.ToInt32(cboStartHour.SelectedItem), Convert.ToInt32(cboStartMinute.SelectedItem),
                             Convert.ToInt32(cboStopHour.SelectedItem), Convert.ToInt32(cboStopMinute.SelectedItem),
                             txtDescription.Text.ToString());

        form.lstEvents.Items.Add(newEvent.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Can you show how you are populating the list box?

Comment: Look like you are populating the listbox with a collection of string. You should be populating it with list of events.

Comment: It'd be helpful to show the definition/type of `lstEvents` and/or tag the question with the UI framework you're using, but the error message describes the problem: there is no conversion between `String` and `Event`.

Comment: Just a tip: you are aware you can take greater control over how the `startTime` is formatted when you use:     `DateTime.ToString()`  example:       `var dateFormatted = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm");` Instead of your override `ToString()`?  Have a look at all the fabulous formats to choose from: [Custom date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'FileItem'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49692559/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-system-string-to-type-fileitem)

Comment: Added list box population @devNull

Comment: @Barns I would love to do it that way, but the rubric says to override ToString() for this format.

Comment: @Sam try removing the ToString. So just `form.lstEvents.Items.Add(newEvent)`

Comment: @devNull Well. I have no idea why but that fixed and the list box still has correct formatting even though I didn't put it through my overridden ToString(). Well, I know why it fixed the String to Object error but I don't know why it still has correct formatting in the list box. Thank you.

Comment: @Sam yup, that's by design :) "The items displayed are usually strings; however, any object can be used. The text that is displayed in the control is the value returned by the object's ToString method." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/add-and-remove-items-from-a-wf-combobox

Comment: You can still override `ToString()`, but instead of constructing the result as you have I strongly suggest that you do so using the `ToString(format)` where "format" is created using [Custom date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Comment: just create a dictionary and store your events.  in the listbox just store a unique name or something to uniquely identify the event.  then you can just find your event in the dictionary by that key

Answer (score -1):

lstEvents.SelectedItem is a String; you want an Event. How you go from a String to an Event is going to depend on what that String is, and what class lstEvents is (and what other properties that class has).

Comment: listEvents is supposed to be a list of Event objects, but I guess I convert it to a string when I put them in the list box. Not sure how else you would display the information in the list box without it being a string.

Comment: Your ToString function will be called when displaying. You can add the Event directly to lstEvents as others have mentioned.